# incompatible pointer types sending 'id' to parameter of type 'SEL_Notnull'

Tags: objective-c, pointers, casting, automatic-ref-counting

```
[contactCell.no5 addTarget:self action:[self performSelector:@selector(numberEdit:cellIndex:) withObject:contactCell.no5 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]] forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

in contactCell.no5  "no5 is textfield" and "contactCell is uitableviewcell object"...

1. incompatible pointer types sending 'id' to parameter of type 'SEL_Notnull'
2. Implicit Conversion of an objective-C Pointer to 'SEL_Notnull' is disallowed with ARC

function-->

```
-(void)numberEdit:(UITextField *)textField cellIndex:(NSNumber *)row
{    
    [numberList removeObjectAtIndex:[row integerValue]];
    NSLog(@"%@",numberList.description);

    [numberList insertObject:textField.text atIndex:[row integerValue]];
    NSLog(@"%@",numberList.description);
}
```

Comment: u got the solution for ur issue... if not can u explain what u r trying to do... why u r getting the error.. @Pratik

Comment: no sir, i can't get the solution. i put 6 text field in 6 different custom cell. i want to send that text field and indexpath of that custom cell where textfield appear from the cellForRowAtIndexPath method to numberEdit:cellIndex: Method...@NAVEENKUMAR

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

if u have textfield like this :

```
UITextField *contactCell;
```

**and u need to add targetLikeThis**

```
 [contactCell addTarget:self action:@selector(numberEdit:cellIndex:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

**fort hais custom action:**

```
-(void)numberEdit:(UITextField *)textField cellIndex:(NSNumber *)row
{    
    [numberList removeObjectAtIndex:[row integerValue]];
    NSLog(@"%@",numberList.description);

    [numberList insertObject:textField.text atIndex:[row integerValue]];
    NSLog(@"%@",numberList.description);
}
```

Comment: sir its not working...there is error in *action*..because *action* accepts *id* type and selector returns *SEL* type...